# Get drive type of path using golang

Tags: go, drive

I want to fetch the drive type (like local, removable etc) from a file path using golang. did not find any built in golang package.

any pointers are appreciated.

Comment: Did you look for non-built-in packages or do any other research? What OS are you looking to do this on?

Comment: Thanks. i am on centos 9. didn't find any non-built-in packages. hence posted here.